# How to use logistic regression for a given session ID from a dataset with many session IDs?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a data set, which has data divided in session IDs (customers) and for each session ID, I have many rows of data (customers'choices). I have to use logistic regression(0 or 1) but with positive value 1 only once for each session Id and rest 0 (Customer chooses only one). 
How do I tell my algo to use each session ID in the data set to predict the choice? (as there are so many customers each having many choices)

edit:
data is something like this

```
Session ID  choice    price    duration  preferred  
1            1          200       2           0  
1            2          300       3           0  
1            3          150       1           1     
1            4          250       2           0  
2            1          150       2           0  
2            2          200       1           1  
2            3          300       1           0
```

Comment: Please provide some data.

Comment: Adding to @akash87's comment, we also need to know what kind of algorithm you plan on using... There must be predictors/explanatory variables on which to base the decision to attribute 0 or 1 to each row. What are those predictors?

Comment: I have added some sample data. I have to predict the 'Preferred' for future data based on the given dataset. My problem is that i am not able to use logistic regression algorithm in this data set for two problem- one is that I don't know how to predict separately for each session ID, and only one preferred is positive in a given session ID

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your logistic regression formula? Still uncertain what your predictors are.